# Better ways to prevent Screen Scraping

Tags: authentication, web-scraping

We have a public facing ASP.Net based web site where third party web sites are accepting our user's credentials and are passing these through to our site to login and after which they are rendering back variations of the our site content.  The issue we have is that our customers are not aware that they are doing this and they are calling into our call-centers looking for support on the external site.
We are considering including a CAPTCHA as one preventative measure however we are worried about the impact to the over user experience.  Other ideas is to surface questions to the user however we would need to dynamically build those questions on the client so as not to flow these back to the requestor through HTML.  Aside from 3rd party offerings, are there any other reliable mechanisms to prevent this type of impersonation, web scraping within our site.

Comment: "accepting our user's credentials"? Start by informing your users not to share their passwords..

Comment: Do the scraped authentication requests not all originate from the same address ranges?

Comment: We have included messaging to our site to inform users to beware.

Comment: Has anyone done any client side DOM changes to render security questions that could further validate the user?  We have certain personal data that we could render on the client.  Is there a simple way to push these questions down to the client then use JScript to inject the UI elements into the DOM at runtime to confirm the user is not a bot?  Was thinking of calling back on Submit to service the rendering a modal dialog with the questions prior to post-back

Comment: Wouldn't they be able to scrape those new UI elements too ? They potentially already have your client's username and passwords, so they could just log in and find out what questions you are asking. I think you need to assume the web scrapers are professional and have developed a set of tools to get around the basic bot detection methods. Dynamically changing your layout using a Javascrript might be more effective, that is what most commercial anti-scraping tools seem to do.

Comment: Sure they could log into one account at a time but its bot-based and as such by changing the question presented every time this would likely spoof their efforts especially given that the question and related input control are rendered client side. I would think these 3rd party sites would soon be render non-usable for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

Could you display CAPTCHAs to certain IP address blocks only, identified based on the number of requests?  I would expect that the scraping third party websites generate a relatively high number of requests. The new CAPTCHAs (are you a human, etc) are far easier to use than the old-style ones, see:

http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/are-you-robot-introducing-no-captcha.html